# Ada toolchain for Windows CE

Tags: ada

Is there an Ada toolchain for Windows CE with a TI AM335X processor?

If there is nothing "out of the box," is it possible to build GCC with Ada support for this platform?

Comment: Must it be native, or would cross-compiling on another machine be acceptable?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Cross-compiling is preferred.

Comment: A commercial option is to use AdaMagic for compiling to ANSI C, and then using the C compiler of your choice. The AdaMagic compiler is available from AdaCore.

Comment: @B98 AdaMagic is apparently made by MapuSoft.  It's not clear what level of runtime support is provided (e.g. is tasking available?), and there does not appear to be an "API" for Windows CE.  But thank you for pointing it out -- I was not aware of its existence.

Comment: According to, e.g., a License Agreement document of theirs, Mapusoft have been using SofCheck's AdaMagic for conversion to C/C++. As noted in a [press release](http://www.adacore.com/press/adacore-sofcheck-merge) about the merger of SofCheck and AdaCore, they might be the best address for inquiries. (Earlier statements were saying that for Ada 95 and much of Ada 2005, only an ANSI C compiler was needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I checked SofCheck AdaMagic from MapuSoft AppCOE. It works, although adabgen.inf and other files are missing, and you'll have to learn it to deal with non-standard compiler.